# I'm continuously repeating code and wondering if there's a way to simplify these if statements

Tags: python, pygame

The code I created is used in pygame to highlight buttons that I am hovering over and when clicked on will trigger their corresponding function

```
if singleplayer_button.collidepoint(mx, my):
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (180, 0, 0), singleplayer_button)
    WIN.blit(singleplayer_button_text, (295, 400))
    if click:
        singleplayer()
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, singleplayer_button)
    WIN.blit(singleplayer_button_text, (295, 400))

if multiplayer_button.collidepoint(mx, my):
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (180, 0, 0), multiplayer_button)
    WIN.blit(multiplayer_button_text, (727, 400))
    if click:
        multiplayer1()
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, multiplayer_button)
    WIN.blit(multiplayer_button_text, (727, 400))

if leaderboard_button.collidepoint(mx, my):
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (180, 0, 0), leaderboard_button)
    WIN.blit(leaderboard_button_text, (291, 550))
    if click:
        leaderboard()
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, leaderboard_button)
    WIN.blit(leaderboard_button_text, (291, 550))

if credit_button.collidepoint(mx, my):
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (180, 0, 0), credit_button)
    WIN.blit(credits_button_text, (774, 550))
    if click:
        credit()
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, credit_button)
    WIN.blit(credits_button_text, (774, 550))

if register_button.collidepoint(mx, my):
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (180, 0, 0), register_button)
    WIN.blit(register_button_text, (300, 700))
    if click:
        register()
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, register_button)
    WIN.blit(register_button_text, (300, 700))

if exit_button.collidepoint(mx, my):
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (180, 0, 0), exit_button)
    WIN.blit(exit_button_text, (737, 700))
    if click:
        exit_window()
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, exit_button)
    WIN.blit(exit_button_text, (737, 700))
```

####_button is a rectangle

####_button_text is text which gets blitted on top the rectangle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read a bout [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Create a `Button` class:

```py
class Button():
    def __init__(self, rect, text, action):
        self.rect = rect
        self.text = text
        self.action = action
    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (180, 0, 0), self.rect)
        WIN.blit(self.text, self.text.get_rect(center = self.rect.center))
    def click(self, mx, my, click):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mx, my) and click:
            self.action()
```

Create a list of `Botton` objects:

```py
buttons = [
    Button(singleplayer_button, singleplayer_button_text, singleplayer),
    Button(multiplayer_button,  multiplayer_button_text,  multiplayer1),
    Button(leaderboard_button,  leaderboard_button_text,  leaderboard),
    Button(credit_button,       credits_button_text,      credit),
    Button(register_button,     register_button_text,     register),
    Button(exit_button,         exit_button_text,         exit_window)
]
```

Draw the buttons in a loop:

```py
for button in buttons:
    button.draw(WIN)
```

Do the click detection in a loop:

```py
for button in buttons:
    button.click(mx, my, click)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, if I could upvote this I would.

Comment: @MinhajRahman Thank you. You're welcome.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up on this. I get and error when I try to run the code   line 147, in draw
    WIN.blit(self.text, self.text.get_rect(center=self.rect.center))
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'get_rect'

Comment: @MinhajRahman Sorry, my bad. There was a typo in the answer. `Button(register_button, register_button_text, register),` instead of `Button(register_button, register_button, register),` (the 2nd argument is `register_button_text`).

Comment: Same for `Button(exit_button, exit_button_text, exit_window)`.

Comment: Ahhhh I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and didn't even notice, thanks again